# django extract only year from date time in queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a purchases table with a column datatime. I would like to select all purchases I have done in the current year. bellow is my code but is not working!

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
year = Purchases.objects.filter(date__year = today.year)
```

I expect the year should be 2018 extracted from 2018-04-12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While querying, we can get year from model field of type `DateField` as `fieldname__year` (for comparision). If we have a field named 'purchase_date' in our model, we can filter data for a particular year as:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(purchase_date__year=targetyear)
```

In your case, if the column name is datatime. You can get the purchases done in current year as:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
purchases = Purchases.objects.filter(datatime__year=today.year)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ExtractYear` function, here is example:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear

qs = Purchases.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('date')).filter(year = today.year)
```